# Updating table data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

At work today, I was updating a database table in oracle.

I tried to update a rows with data 6 with 42 for users in certain category.

But, instead, I left out the user and I updated a whole table with with 42 for all users with 6 in "that" column.

I am using pl/sql developer.  I clicked `yes` to post to database.

I know that updates are autocommit command.

I don't know exactly how many rows were affected, but I know there are no more users with 6 in that column and all of the users with the 6 in that column now has 42 in there.

**Question**

Is there a way I can undo this mistake?

Comment: If you committed the changes (probably with autocommit), than you will have to use a backup.  If autocommit did not apply, try "rollback" (not sure which rdms you are using) in exactly that session/window in which you executed the update statement.

Comment: I did try rollback and data did not rollback.  I did not backup any tables.  I am using oracle 11 with pl/sql developer.  Is there an easy way to recover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have good luck, you could use something like `FLASHBACK TABLE abc  TO TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '15' minute)`.
Unfortunately, this requires that you had movement enabled before your update statement (which is unlikely that you had).

So I suppose that - in absence of a backup - there is no way to get back the information :-(

But this is just my opinion; I'd suggest to - if possible - leave the DB as is until somebody comes up with better ideas. Before doing anything now - note that operations might truncate logs (which some one else with better ideas would require) - rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you, for the information. I cannot do anything until tomorrow morning. I cannot believe I was so stupid.  Hope they don't fire me.   I hope I will be able to figure out or the guy knows how to turn it back with a script, since these columns are triggered by data in certain columns

Comment: Yeah, I was told without a backup, there is no way to get the information.  Thanks for your responses, Stephan Lechner.  I am trying to see if I can create a schema of production database, and input the data from the test server into it and then run the production schemas against each other.  or something of that matter, as I was told.  I ll see.